# PHP Get XML from Remote URL with Authentication - 403 Error

Tags: php, xml, curl, pear, http-request

I have a URL which gives an xml output. It requires a username and password which I can access through a browser using the format:

```
http://username:password@url.com
```

However when I try to access it through a php file I get a 403 forbidden:

```
$url = "http://username:password@url.com";


$xml = @simplexml_load_file($url);
print_r($http_response_header);
```

I have tried using curl and setting the user agent to a browser but this still doesn't echo the data.

```
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$process = curl_init("http://user:pass@url.com/feed?feed_id=1");
//curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$return = curl_exec($process);
echo $return;
```

I also tried using pear's http request 2, which also gives a 403 forbidden

Is the server i'm trying to access refusing all connections via PHP or is there a way around this?
Thanks!

Comment: try removing the user:pass in curl init and also add a browser user agent to header.

Comment: thanks how do I add a browser user agent?

Comment: curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5'); something like this.

Comment: this still gives a 403 forbidden

Comment: I just saw use a get request instead of post

Comment: Since you are already setting up the `CURLOPT_PASSWD` option, i would suggest to remove `user:pass@` **from** `$process = curl_init("http://user:pass@url.com/feed?feed_id=1");`

Comment: i tried that and still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Seems the page you are requesting is very picky. Make sure to send all the headers exactly as the browser does.

- Install Firebug in Firefox, or use Chrome's inspector
- Write down all the headers that get sent when you request the protected page
- Send the headers from your php script exactly as the browser does.
- If it does not work, use Wireshark to verify that you really got it right.

I suspect the page also looks for a user-agent header or so, not only the password.

Another problem could be that you have a different IP than your server, and that only your IP is whitelisted.